# UIButton with CAShapeLayer makes title disappear while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, cashapelayer

I have a `ProfileCollectionViewCell`with one method:

```
func configureCellWithProfile(profile: Profile) {

    shapeLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()

    let path = CGPathCreateMutable()

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 0, 0)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, CGRectGetWidth(likeButton.frame), 0)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, CGRectGetWidth(likeButton.frame), CGRectGetHeight(likeButton.frame))
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path)

    shapeLayer.fillColor = profile.favourite ? UIColor.brilliantRose().CGColor : UIColor.blackSqueeze().CGColor
    shapeLayer.path = path

    likeButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
    likeButton.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

And just after load it looks like this:

[image]

but after I scroll my title (heart from icomoon font) disappear:

[image]

**Why?**

Comment: print `likeButton.frame` and see what happen while scrolling, or there are something wrong with your reuse

Comment: I solved the problem... layer covered my `titleLabel`.:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem, replacing:

```
likeButton.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

with

```
likeButton.layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, below: likeButton.titleLabel?.layer)
```