# UIButton title disappear when scrolling UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I use this to make the size of the button dynamically, everything is ok, but when I scroll, sometimes the title of many buttons disappear, when I scroll again the title appears. Any help please.

[image]

This's the image when the text disappears.

[image]

This when the text appear again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a layer to your button:

```
yourButton.layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, below: yourButton.titleLabel?.layer)
```

**`shapeLayer`** is the shape's button.

[Check this response if it's useful for your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38218283/uibutton-with-cashapelayer-makes-title-disappear-while-scrolling)

Comment: I used the storyboard for the button, I did not draw them programmatically